# Spinnaker base-url doesn't working by URL path setting

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I try to set URL Path to spin-gate base-url at spinnaker.

`hal config security api edit --override-base-url http://example.com/api`

And now, I accessed spinnaker ui.

but it doesn’t work at 
`http://example.com/api/credentials`
and
`http://example.com/api/webhook/preconfigured` API.

It returned 404 error. Can you tell me why?
[image: Browser Inspect - Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

try this out.

```
echo "host: 0.0.0.0" | tee \
    ~/.hal/default/service-settings/gate.yml \
    ~/.hal/default/service-settings/deck.yml

hal config security ui edit --override-base-url http://<deck-loadbalancer-dns-entry>:9000
hal config security api edit --override-base-url http://<gate-loadbalancer-dns-entry>:8084
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo hal deploy apply
sudo hal deploy connect
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged because they provide insight on how the problem was solved. Please update your answer to include an explanation of how your code solves the OP's problem :)